# Reload page with new parameters

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a popup window and when I click a button it will close that window and reload the parent window with new parameters.  For example the url is `page.apsx?id=oldparameter`, the parent reloaded with new parameter like `page.aspx?id=newparameter`

I have something like:

```
object newparameter = r[“id”];
string url = “~/page.aspx?id=” +newparameter ;
```

Then I tried this:

```
Response.Write("<script  language='javascript'> {window.opener.document.forms[0].elements['id'].value = '" + url + "'; top.close();}</script>");
```

But it doesn’t work.  Can somebody show me how to do this?  Thank you very much.

Comment: You're initialing the page change on the server side? Why do you need to do it in JavaScript then? What exactly does that `Response` correspond to - where is that code, in a button click handler?

Comment: Yes, it is under button click handler. I don't understand javascript very well. Here is the following error measseage:Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'window.opener.document.forms.0.elements.username' is null or not an object

Comment: For one, you can't use ~ in the JS URLs like you do in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

I Think instead of this `Response.Write`  you need `ScriptManager.RegisterStartUpScript`

```
string Script = "window.opener.document.forms[0].elements['id'].value = '" + url + "'; top.close();";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "key", Script , true);
```

I Think This will work